# How to annotate a property as Optional in C#

Tags: c#, annotations

I have a class in which I serialize to XML.

When I read (`Deserialize`) the XML the `ReadOnly` attribute may or may not be present.

How can I mark this as optional, and or required ?

Currently

```
    [XmlAttribute("ReadOnly")]
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.readOnly; }
        set { this.readOnly = value; }

    }
```

Something like this is what Im after

```
    [XmlAttribute("ReadOnly", AttributeType.Optional)]
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.readOnly; }
        set { this.readOnly = value; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default everything is optional and the deserializer will just not populate things that are not specified.

If you want to validate that required attributes are present, you could, for instance, use an XSD schema and validate against that.

Comment: OK great thanks. I was under the assumption everything was required.